# Placing code from webform into class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some code in a button_click event in my webform that performs some actions
(writing some xml files).

But i wish to place all my XML code in 1 class within my webproject.

But how do i exactly acces controls from my webform on this class?
And how do i  link those 2 with each other?

Ive tried inherit from System.Web.UI.Page in my class but seems thats not quite it.

Kind Regards.

Comment: What do you have so far in your webform (aspx and cs/vb files)?

Comment: just a apx. file and a apx.cs file. I simply want to move the code within my button click event to this class that will contain all my XML related coding.

Answer (score 4):

Create a class that has the logic to write your XML file and receives the data though parameter. That class does not access your web controls. Now in your code behind in your click handler, you take the data from the control, instantiate your XML writer class and call the method with the data as parameter

```
Button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = MyControl.Text;
    var writer = new MyWriterClass();
    writer.WriteToXml(data);
}
```

Comment: But what exactly do i change in the class thats located in App_Data because its totally unaccesable and cannot find what to add.

Comment: You need to place your writer class in the App_Code folder so it gets compiled....